# Image view Layout Alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to develop my first android app and facing some issues to set images as desired.I want to set one image at **top center**,text in **mid center** and other two images at **bottom left** and **bottom right**.Please guide

Like this:

[image]

The layout I wrote:

```
   <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView

         android:id="@+id/ASFlogo"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         android:scaleType="fitStart"
         android:src="@drawable/asff" />

     <ImageView

         android:id="@+id/SFALogo"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         android:scaleType="fitEnd"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
         android:src="@drawable/sfal" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/slogan"
         android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

     <ImageView

         android:id="@+id/DAkks"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         android:scaleType="fitEnd"
         android:src="@drawable/dakks_logolar_con" />
 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout, but replace with your images/text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ASFlogo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_205" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text111111111"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SFALogo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_205" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DAkks"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_205" />
</RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I recommend you to check the ConstraintLayout, it will be easier. [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView

     android:id="@+id/A"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:src="@drawable/asff" />


 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/slogan"
     android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
     android:textSize="20sp" />

 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView

     android:id="@+id/B"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
     android:scaleType="fitEnd"
     android:src="@drawable/dakks_logolar_con" />
      <ImageView

     android:id="@+id/C"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
     android:scaleType="fitEnd"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
     android:src="@drawable/sfal" />
     </LinearLayout>
```